How do the `hitTestBehavior` and `opaque` correlate in `MouseRegion` widget in Flutter?
All know the widget MouseRegion which contains properties hitTestBehavior and opaque. How these both properties are correlate? What is the widget behavior in below cases? When should yo use opaque or/and hitTestBehavior?
MouseReqion(
  opaque: true,
  hitTestBehavior: HitTestBehavior.transluent,
)

or
MouseReqion(
  opaque: false,
  hitTestBehavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
)

or
MouseReqion(
  opaque: false|true,
  hitTestBehavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
)


this is the only place where it is used (at least my web based findings say so): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/main/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart#L3157 so if it is false every hit tests are also false
